# TLAB in Virtual Thread - Project Loom

Tags: java, project-loom

How currently TLAB is handling in Virtual Thread introduced by Project Loom in Java?
Is TLAB available in virtual threads?

Comment: Why do you think they are not available? Please note that I expect this to be not per virtual thread but per physical thread that can run virtual threads. (A virtual thread that is not executed by a physical thread cannot allocate memory and therefore also doesn't need a TLAB).

Comment: What do you mean cannot allocate memory? In virtual thread we can allocate objects  it question is how is coordinate with TLAB? I am not sure but I am wondering that virtual thread allocates outside of TLAB

Comment: I am wondering about this because TLAB is reserved space for thread but we can create thousands of them so I assumed that it is not possible for create thousands of TLAB because they are quickly creating and terminating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual threads don't have a TLAB - they don't need it.

From [Going inside Java’s Project Loom and virtual threads](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/going-inside-javas-project-loom-and-virtual-threads):

> Obviously, at some point, virtual threads must be attached to an actual OS thread to execute. These OS threads upon which a virtual thread executes are called *carrier threads* .

If a virtual thread is not attached to a carrier thread is not executing any instructions and therefore cannot allocate memory - it doesn't need a TLAB.

If it is attached to a carrier thread it is executing instructions and therefore can allocate memory. For this memory allocations it can safely use the TLAB of the carrier thread.

No contention here:

- at any point in time a carrier thread is executing exactly one virtual thread
- at any point in time a virtual thread is executed by at most one carrier thread